# -webkit-transform and accommodating the cascade (how to not over-ride previous settings)

Tags: webkit, css, transform, cascade

The dilemma:

In my CSS file, I have this:

```
div {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

In my jQuery, I then later do this:

```
$('div).css('-webkit-transform','rotate(3deg)')
```

What happens (as you can maybe guess) is that setting -webkit-transform inline via jQuery over-rides the original setting. Normally this is fine/expected. But the issue here is that I'm actually setting two entirely different styles (scale and rotatation) but due to how webkit uses the same property name for both, one 'over-rides' the other.

Can anyone think of an elegant way to handle this? The best I can think of is to come up with a jQuery function that will parse this particular style and append to/subtract from a comma delimited list of values (akin to remove/addClass). That still may be a challenge, though, if one is dynamically updating nested elements all with different transformations. (for instance, I have a wrapper DIV that I want scale to apply to (and its children). One of the children also need to do a rotation, but still preserve the scale).

UPDATE:

Upon further investigation, this appears to not necessarily be a DOM updating issue but rather just an odd CSS cascade issue.

Sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
      #parentSpan {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.25);
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="parentSpan" style="
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid orange;
      width: 600px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
      ">
    hello
    </span>
```

I'm setting a scale style in the HEAD and then a rotate style inline. The inline rotate completely over-rides the scale since they are both '-webkit-transform' properties. Is that just the way it is?

UPDATE 2:

I think I have a workaround.

Turns out, I don't think this is an inheritance issue. My above example is over-writing the transform declaration, not adding to (inheritance).

The workaround would appear to add some extra markup. Apply the scale transform to a wrapper div, then apply the rotation transform to a child div. That child div will then have rotation AND also be scaled down visually due to the parent being scaled.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the way CSS is supposed to work, you're overriding the -webkit-transform property with a later/more specific definition.  You could try something like:

```
$('div').css('-webkit-transform', $('div').css('-webkit-transform') + ' rotate(3deg)')
```

Or you could do a special case for the `div` that already has the transform set.

Comment: Bummer. This seems to be a flawed design in the case of Webkit. The cascade makes perfect sense when the properties are distinct (a border is a border, padding is padding) but in the case of this browser-specific property, the styles are actually doing entirely different things. Your sample is along the lines of what I was thinking. I'd have to built out a full parser, though. And since the style inherits, I'd have to walk the DOM each time I want to update something. That would get tricky and performance costing.

Comment: Actually...I thought about this some more (see update #2). I think your idea is definitely viable. The issue isn't inheritance from parents getting over-ridden, but, as you state, the fact that I am re-writing the actual transform property values on the same object. As such, I wouldn't have to traverse the DOM at all and merely grab the value of the transform, parse it out into an array, then append/remove as needed (akin to how jQuery deals with add/removeClass). Good idea!

Comment: Though I still wonder why Apple considered '-webkit-transform: scale(.5)' made more sense than '-webkit-transform-scale: .5'?

Comment: @DA What you need is a `-webkit-transform-rotate` and a `-webkit-transform-scale`, similar to how you currently have `background` shorthand but also `background-image`, `background-repeat` etc.  You should suggest it on the [csswg mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/).

Comment: @DA: You can't have separate properties for this because the order of the transforms is important. Sometimes you want to rotate before translating, and sometimes vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is sort of expected, because the transformation depends on the order in which the transformations are stated. It's different if you skew and then rotate than if you rotate and then skew (they produce different shapes) and this doesn't bode well with the cascading declarations.

Unfortunately, the facilites for getting around this in webkit are quite clunky, here is an example:

```
function getMatrix() {
  var element = document.getElementById("whatever");
  var transform = window.getComputedStyle(element).webkitTransform;
  return matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(transform);
}


$("#smaller").click(function(){
   getMatrix();
  $("#whatever").css("webkit-transform", matrix.scale(0.8));
});

$("#bigger").click(function(){
   getMatrix();
  $("#whatever").css("webkit-transform", matrix.scale(1.2));
});

$("#rotate").click(function(){
   getMatrix();
  $("#whatever").css("webkit-transform", matrix.rotate(5));
});

$("#invert").click(function(){
   getMatrix();
  $("#whatever").css("webkit-transform", matrix.inverse(1));
});
```

You can see it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/VSqZt/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your application is organized, you can encapsulate the various transform properties and then apply them all to your element with one transform rule.

For example:

The div you wish to transform is represented by a view or object. Give the view properties for the various transforms you wish to control. From your example, scale and rotate. Modify these properties on the view then update/render the element to set all transform properties at once.

```
var view = {
    scale: 1.0,
    rotate: "0deg",
    render: function() {
        $("#some-element").css("-webkit-transform", "scale("+this.scale+") rotate("+this.rotate+")");
    }
}

view.scale = 2.0;
view.rotate = "45deg";

view.render();
```